# TFS 15 RC1 - Build agent not running/working - no agent pool found with identifier

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We currently have upgraded our Team Foundation Server 2015 to Team foundation server 15, RC1. 
But i cannot get our existing or new build agents running. The error we got is always the same.
No agent pool found with identifier 1 (or 2, ....).

I have checked the database and there is an agent pool with that ID.

Any idea anyone?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the build agent pool definitely exists, but the error is can't find the agent pool. Then the issue is very likely related to permissions.

When configuring the build agent(new created or existed), you need to make sure the account which running the configure command or script have **enough permission**.

The user account needs to be part of the **Agent Pool Administrator Accounts**.

---

**Update**

Try below ways to narrow  down the issue:

1. First check in  that if the build server is available and enabled in
   TFS at `https://YOURCOMPANYNAME:8080/tfs/_admin/_AgentQueue`, and
   your build agent should be “Green”.
2. Make sure the agent is in **interactive mode**.
3. Try to change a domain account which is a member of the **Build
   Agent    Service Accounts group** and belongs to "Agent Pool Service
   Account"    role, to see whether the agent would work or not.
4. Double check whether there are some Firewall interface block the
   build, try to disable all related settings.

---

**Update 2**

Browse the **Control Panel** - Team Project Collection - Team Project- Agent queues- click agent pool - Roles- click **Add...** - Add your user ID and select **Administrator** in **Role**

After this try again.

[image]

Comment: I have double checked the permissions, and the user i ran the powershell command's, is in the agent pool administrator accounts and in fact is in the group team foundation server administrators

Any more idea's left?

Comment: Hi,
First of all, thanks for taking your time!

1. The agent is red (offline), because of the fact i cannot start the agent i guess
2. i start the agent in interactive mode, but it's not starting (error no agent pool is found with identifier 1).
3. Account is domain account and in the build agent service accounts and belongs to agent pool service account.
4. Firewall is off, still the same issue.

Comment: What's the result if you click manage agent pool? Could you see the agent pool in there. You can add a screenshot in the agent queue  to show the status in your question. Moreover, how about create a new agent pool as a workaround?

Comment: I can see the agent pool, i can see the agents, i can create new agents, that's all good, but i cannot start them, they can't find the agent pool

Comment: I have also created new agent pool, same result, the agent cannot find the pool.

Comment: After my test, I still think this is related to the permissions. Could you try to use another account such as the one  install TFS or create the team project collection /team project to configure the agent. Or you can also try to add your role ID with Administrator permission  in the agent  queue. Detail steps please refer my update answer.

Comment: And also make sure there is nothing error in you ps script. I have followed the one  in this blog: https://nkdagility.com/configure-a-build-vnext-agent-on-vso/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time, however the issue is solved with Microsoft support.
It turned out that my default access level was stakeholder, while build permissions are in the basic. So i had to change the default access level to Basic.
That's obvious a bug in the new RC1, but like you said, it was some kind of a permission issue.

thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same thing: an existing build server, which was working until somebody upgraded it.  Error message in the .\BuildAgent_Diag\ folder kept saying

```
Failed to create session. Sleeping for 10 seconds before next retry
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskAgentPoolNotFoundException: No agent pool found with identifier 7.
```

I already had the service running as a domain account with "build admin" permissions.

The solution was to run 'ConfigureAgent' again: Open a command prompt as administrator.  Change directory to your 'BuildAgent' folder (or where ever your 'ConfigureAgent.cmd' file is located) and run 'ConfigureAgent.cmd'.  It will ask a few questions. I stayed with the current settings.  I had to enter the password for the service account.  Eventually the wizard completed and everything worked again.